# How to zip or unzip a local file or folder using Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, jszip, adm-zip

First, I am new to AngularJs. Now i am trying to zip a local file or local folder using angular JS. I have analyzed some methods as follows,

1. [JS Zip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/)

   In this JS Zip there is no support to zip the local file and local folder.
2. [Adm-zip](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/working-with-zip-files-in-node-js/)

   The above tool is Javascript implementation of zip for nodejs. Allows user to create or extract zip files both in memory or to/from disk.

My question as follows,

1. Is there any possibility in angular JS to zip a local file or folder from client side?
2. Otherwise is there any possibility to use the adm-zip javascript implementation tool to zip the local file or folder from client side?

Anyone help will be appreciated!!!

Comment: IMO,You can't directly use local system from client side.To implement your use case , you have to use server to extract zip.